# Using array elements as relative URLs in a django template

Tags: python, html, django

I am totally new to django, and have been struggling with the following issue for a while.
I am sending a sorted list of lists to a template from views.py to a template, in which each sublist (containing two elements) should be displayed. I would like the first element to be a link, in such a way that the String content should be the relative URL to be displayed.

So I used the following syntax:

```
<a href="{% url {{user.0}} %}">{{user.0}}</a>
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /app/best_travelled/
Could not parse the remainder: '{{user.0}}' from '{{user.0}}'
```

Please find below the relevant code snippets:

views.py:

```
def best_travelled(request):

    trips = Trip.objects.all()
    user_trips={}
    for trip in trips:
        user_trips[trip.owner] = user_trips.get(trip.owner,0)+1

    user_list = []
    for key, value in sorted(user_trips.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True):
        user_list.append([key, value])  
    context_dict = {'user_list':user_list}
    return render(request,'best_travelled.html',context_dict)
```

Template:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Most Recent Trips - Travelmate</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Best-Travelled</h1>
  <div>
    {% if user_list %}
    <ol>
      {% for user in user_list %}
      <a href="{% url {{user.0}} %}">{{user.0}}</a>
      <li>{{user.0}}, Number of trips: {{user.1}}</li>

      {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    {% else %} There are no travellers yet! This is your chance to become the very first one! <br /> {% endif %}


    <a href="{% url 'add_trip' %}">Add a New Trip</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

And for the profiles:

views.py

```
@login_required
def view_profile(request,username):


    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    trips = Trip.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    context_dict = {'user':user, 'trips':trips }

   return render(request,'view_profile.html',context_dict)
```

app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^pop_trips/$', views.pop_trips, name='pop_trips'),
    url(r'^recent_trips/$', views.recent_trips, name='recent_trips'),
    url(r'^best_travelled/$', views.best_travelled, name='best_travelled'),
    url(r'^most_active_travellers/$', views.contact, name='most_active_travellers'),

    url(r'^passport/$', views.passport, name='passport'),
    url(r'^add_trip/$', views.add_trip, name='add_trip'),

    url(r'^settings/$', views.settings, name='settings'),
    url(r'^my_trips/$', views.my_trips, name='my_trips'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile')
]
```

project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', app_views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',auth_views.logout,name='logout'),
    url(r'^oauth/',include('social_django.urls',namespace='social')),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/',include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w\-]+)/$', app_views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Thanks heaps to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `{{` for variables inside `{%`. Just write:

```
<a href="{% url user.0 %}">{{user.0}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

`<a href="{% url 'url_name' arg_1 arg_2 %}">{{user.0}}</a>`

Considering you have:

`url(r'my-url/(?P<arg_1>[0-9a-f-]+)/(?P<arg_2>[a-f-]+)/$', MyClassView.as_view(), name="url_name"),`

Where:

- `url_name` is the `name` of your `url`
- `arg_1` and `arg_1` are your `arguments` for your url(if there is the case, if not stays without them).

like:  `<a href="{% url 'url_name' %}">{{user.0}}</a>`

**Side-note:**
Once you are **{% `here` %}** all the context pushed is available without any extra `{{` and `}}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It does find the string I want and create a URL, but now I get this error:
oReverseMatch at /app/best_travelled/
Reverse for 'test123' not found. 'test123' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
however, if i go to site.com/app/test123, it is there like I expect it

Comment: I figured it out, it has to be:
    <a href="{% url 'view_profile' user.0 %}">{{user.0}}</a>